# Use html page in lightbox?

Tags: html, lightbox

I have 2 html files. I want to use one html form in light box. 
so that when i clink a button on form the other form open in lightbox. 
Plz share any informative link. I search google but not find correctly.

Answer (score 1):

from [website](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/):

> Can I display flash, video, or other
>   content using the script?
>   Sorry, photos only. For other content, google for Lightbox
>   modifications or try an alternative
>   script such as Cody Lindley's
>   ThickBox.

Comment: I try to use <a href="http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/">PrettyPhoto</a> but it disturb the layout of my 2nd form that show in lightbox..

Comment: i would suggest using http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ (just for up-to-date-thinking) and inspect the css-classes. also: ensure that you are doing an iframe, not an internal content!